# here i want to pass the id in url using codeigniter

Tags: php, uri

this is the code i have in views . i want to pass the id value in url but it shows the following error

> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Trying to get property of non-object
>
> Filename: views/cameralist.php

**view code**

```
<?php
foreach($field as $f)
if($f !="id"){
{?>
<div class="values"><?php
echo $f."<br>"; ?></div><br><br><br>
<?php 
echo "<a href = '".base_url()."index.php/product/edit/".$f->id."'>Edit</a>"; 
echo "<a href = '".base_url()."index.php/product/delete/".$f->id."'>Delete</a>"; 
}
}
?>
```

Any suggestion?

Thanks

**Model code**

```
function get_field(){
     $result = $this->db->list_fields('camera_details');
     foreach($result as $field){    
            $data[] = $field;
     }
    return $data;
}
```

**controller code**

```
function cameralist(){
    $this->load->model('p_model');
    $data['field'] = $this->p_model->get_field();
    $this->load->view('cameralist',$data);
}
```

Comment: Can you show us what's the structure of the variable $f in that $field array? Try to print_r() or var_dump() it. It's definitely not an object, so that's why you're getting that error. It might be an array, in which case you could use $f['id'], but it would be better to see it first.

Comment: i have added all the codes now tell me your suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**list_fields()** will echo column names of the supplied database table name. That's why it's returning with an error saying you cannot get the offset of a string.

So change your model code to:

```
function get_field()
{
   return $this->db->field_data('camera_details');
}
```

Also your fields will be returned as objects, so stick with the object property syntax:

```
"index.php/product/edit/".$f->id.
```

In the future if you run into an issue where you don't know what is returned, you should just try to dump results like this for example:

```
$result = $this->db->list_fields('camera_details');
var_dump(results)
```

Would have displayed the following:

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  string(2) "id"
  [1]=>
  string(4) "name"
  [2]=>
  string(5) "price"
  [3]=>
  string(10) "lennsensor"
  [4]=>
  string(5) "thick"
}
```

Comment: i have changed like above code but it shows  _A PHP Error was encountered Severity: 4096 Message: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string_ like this

Comment: I've simplified the code for your model, please try to dump it in your controller code before you feed it into your view to see what format do you have in there.

Comment: i understand. but i want to get the fields from db dynamically but you have done in static method. that's main thing i want to do.

Comment: now i have edited everything. and posted what i have in controller , model and view folders now tell me the suggestion

Answer (score 0):

**Your model Code**

```
function get_field(){
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM camera_details");
return $query->result();
}
```

**View Code**

```
foreach ($field as $f)
{   echo "<td>".$f->id."</td>"; 
    echo "<a href = '".base_url()."index.php/product/edit/".$f->id."'>Edit</a>"; 
    echo "<a href = '".base_url()."index.php/product/delete/".$f->id."'>Delete</a>"; 
}
?>
```

Change code in your model. This will work now

Comment: it s not working      shows an error called _Message: Illegal string offset 'id'_

Comment: Can you share the output of `$f`. Is that `id` field available in your array.

Comment: _id name price lennsensor thick_    these are my $f fields

Comment: now i have edited everything. and posted what i have in controller , model and view folders now tell me the suggestion